# Is it safe to hardcode an API secret on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm going to be making queries to Balanced's credit card processing servers using tokens stored in the App Engine datastore. This requires using an API secret string for the queries. If I hardcode the API secret into my app code and disable source downloading by admins, is there any way for a potentially malicious admin (who doesn't know the secret) to find out what the secret is (assuming it's in the code, not the datastore)?

I'm using Google App Engine for Java. The API secret is just a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no "potentially malicious" people have access to your source code, it is perfectly safe to include an API secret in your server-side code.

All samples for App Engine to API code include "hardcoded" API/client secrets. For example: [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate).

Comment: aren't all users "potentially malicious" when we're speaking about security?

Comment: API secrets are typically used to make calls from App Engine instances to API services. Web clients and end users are not involved in this process.

Comment: fair enough... for some reason I was under the impression this would be customer-facing code.  Having looked at it more in depth... you,re totally right, there is actually no reason (or real way) to do it otherwise

Comment: Thanks so much! and it's impossible for an admin to get the bin's or anything from which the source can be reverse-engineered?

Comment: Without access to the source code, there is no access to any of its folders or any directories on an App Engine instance. If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it. And welcome to StackOverflow!